# Google chart size on initial load

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-visualization

So I have this Google chart that I created and on the initial load, the chart is tiny. I want the chart to be responsive which it is when I change the screen size but not on the initial load.

Note- I have a dropdown to select the different charts.

Here's the code to help you see.

Css:

```
#chart_div {
     width: 1200px !important;
     height: 700px !important;
 }

 @media (max-width: 992px) {
    
     #chart_div {
         width: 350px !important;
         height: 400px !important;
     }

    
 }
```

Html:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <div id="chart_div" style="display: inline-block;"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var currentChartType = 'total';
function drawChart() {
    
    data.addRows(rows);
    var options = {
        chart: {
            title: 'Acres Over Time for Serial Numbers',
            subtitle: 'Date vs Acres',
        },
        hAxis: {
            format: 'd MMM',
            gridlines: {
                count: rows.length
            },
            minorGridlines: {
                count: 0
            }
        },
        vAxis: {
            title: 'Total Area',
        }
    };
    var chartDiv = document.getElementById('chart_div');
    var chart1 = new google.visualization.LineChart(chartDiv);
    chart1.draw(data, options);
    window.addEventListener('resize', drawChart, false);
}

function drawChartTime() {
    // Populate data
    var rows = [];
    var dateMap = new Map();
    for (var i = 0; i < machines.length; i++) {
        var serialNumber = machines[i]['SerialNr'];
        var date = new Date(machines[i].Date);
        if (!dateMap.has(date)) {
            dateMap.set(date, {});
        }
        dateMap.get(date)[serialNumber] = machines[i].TotalTime;
    }

    dateMap.forEach((serialNumbersData, date) => {
        var row = [date];
        serialNumbers.forEach(serialNumber => {
            row.push(serialNumbersData[serialNumber] || null);
        });
        rows.push(row);
    });

    data.addRows(rows);

    var options = {
        chart: {
            title: 'Acres Over Time for Serial Number ' + serialNumber,
            subtitle: 'Total Duration (hr)',
        },
        hAxis: {
            format: 'd MMM',
            gridlines: {
                count: rows.length
            },
            minorGridlines: {
                count: 0
            }
        },
        vAxis: {
            title: 'Total Duration',
        }
    };

    var chartDiv = document.getElementById('chart_div');
    var chart2 = new google.visualization.LineChart(chartDiv);
    chart2.draw(data, options);
    window.addEventListener('resize', drawChartTime, false);
}

function drawSelectedChart(selectedChartType) {
    if (selectedChartType === 'default') {
        drawDefaultChart();
    } else if (selectedChartType === 'time') {
        drawChartTime();
    } else if (selectedChartType === 'total') {
        drawChart();
    }
}

function switchChart() {
    var chartSelector = document.getElementById('chartSelector');
    var selectedChartType = chartSelector.value;
    currentChartType = selectedChartType;
    drawSelectedChart(currentChartType);
}

      
google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function () {
    // Draw the default chart initially
    drawSelectedChart(currentChartType);
});
```

I tried hard coding the size in the options which works but not reponsize. I've also done CSS styling which seems to work for the responsiveness but is tiny on the initial load.

Comment: Can't you provide a Fiddle to understand your problem ? Why your div is `inline-block` ?

Answer (score 0):

To make the Google Chart responsive on initial load you could start by dynamically setting its dimensions.

#### CSS

```css
#chart_div {
    width: 1200px !important;
    height: 700px !important;
}

@media (max-width: 992px) {
    #chart_div {
        width: 350px !important;
        height: 400px !important;
    }
}
```

#### HTML

```html
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <div id="chart_div" style="display: inline-block;"></div>
</div>
```

#### JavaScript

```js
var currentChartType = 'total';

function setChartDimensions() {
    var chartDiv = document.getElementById('chart_div');
    if (window.innerWidth <= 992) {
        chartDiv.style.width = '350px';
        chartDiv.style.height = '400px';
    } else {
        chartDiv.style.width = '1200px';
        chartDiv.style.height = '700px';
    }
}

google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(function () {
    setChartDimensions();
    drawSelectedChart(currentChartType);
});

function drawChart() {
    // Your existing data and options setup
    var data = /* your data */;
    var options = {
        chart: {
            title: 'Acres Over Time for Serial Numbers',
            subtitle: 'Date vs Acres',
        },
        hAxis: {
            format: 'd MMM',
            gridlines: {
                count: 7 // example
            },
            minorGridlines: {
                count: 0
            }
        },
        vAxis: {
            title: 'Total Area',
        }
    };

    var chartDiv = document.getElementById('chart_div');
    var chart1 = new google.visualization.LineChart(chartDiv);
    chart1.draw(data, options);
    window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
        setChartDimensions();
        drawChart();
    }, false);
}

function drawChartTime() {
    // Your existing data and options setup for time-based chart
    // ...

    var chartDiv = document.getElementById('chart_div');
    var chart2 = new google.visualization.LineChart(chartDiv);
    chart2.draw(data, options);
    window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
        setChartDimensions();
        drawChartTime();
    }, false);
}

function drawSelectedChart(selectedChartType) {
    if (selectedChartType === 'default') {
        drawDefaultChart();
    } else if (selectedChartType === 'time') {
        drawChartTime();
    } else if (selectedChartType === 'total') {
        drawChart();
    }
}

function switchChart() {
    var chartSelector = document.getElementById('chartSelector');
    var selectedChartType = chartSelector.value;
    currentChartType = selectedChartType;
    drawSelectedChart(currentChartType);
}
```

Here, I added a function called `setChartDimensions` that adjusts the chart size based on the window width. It's initially invoked when Google Charts finishes loading and also re-invoked upon window resizing. This should handle the responsiveness and initial sizing issue.